# Example on Web Service Consumption using Spring if provided a WSDL

Tags: spring, spring-ws

Hi Im a newbie to Spring WebServices. I would like to go through a standard example wherein the WSDL is provided as input from Provider.
Now how will the client code for this WSDL looks like. Do we need to generate a stub code at client side??

Comment: YOu;ve read the client docs at http://static.springsource.org/spring-ws/sites/1.5/reference/html/client.html, right?

Comment: yes i have gone through but that doesnt answer my requirements

Comment: that example doesnt contain WSDL URL at all. It was simple String message but my project contains WSDL with wrapper request objects

Answer (score 9):

I will recommend generating the request and response objects with JAXB from the provider's XSD schemas.

You don't need to generate the service classes with Spring WS since it uses a template class to communicate against the WS server. If you're familiar with Spring JDBC or Spring JMS, the template class behaves quite similar to the `JMSTemplate` and `JdbcTemplate` classes.

Actually, the Spring WS client doesn't need the WSDL document at all! In addition to XSD schemas, you only need to set the URI property on the WebServiceTemplate bean like this example does:

```
<bean id="webServiceTemplate"
    class="org.springframework.ws.client.core.WebServiceTemplate">     

    <property name="marshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="unmarshaller" ref="marshaller" />
    <property name="defaultUri"
        value="http://localhost:8081/ws-demo/account-balance-service" />
</bean>
```

Here's a [tutorial](http://blog.espenberntsen.net/2010/02/28/spring-ws-client/) that might give you some answers.

Answer (score 3):

See if this step by step tutorial on - Web Service Client with Spring-WS - is helpful -  at http://justcompiled.blogspot.com/2010/11/web-service-client-with-spring-ws.html